# Excel Vba:- Display a cell value if a match is found in a row

Tags: vba, excel

My question may be a little confusing.

I am trying to find the count of no of times a number matched in a sheet but it should not count if a number comes multiple times in a single row. It count it 1 only for each row.

A     B      C     D       Status
  1    id1    day1   val1    Resolved
  2    id2    id1    id1     Not Resolved
  3    id3    day1   val3    Not Resolved
  4    id1    day2   id1     Resolved
  5    id2    day2   val2    Not Resolved
  6    id3    day2   val3    Not Resolved

So if i searched for id1 it must give a count of 3 not 5 as it is repeated in 2 & 4th row.
And it should also display its status like 2 Resolved 1 Not Resolved because 1&4th Resolved so count is 2 Resolved and 2nd Row is Not Resolved.

Any help is greatly appreciated.. And please give suggestion of Vba code..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code you have developed so far. If not started. Please start and update your question with code and the issue you are facing. Here are my pointers.

Comment: do a Row.Find for each row and if , found a match, increment a counter variable by 1, iterate the same operation throgh all your rows. Not much complicated stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you are looking for "id1", in an array of i rows and j columns, with the first cell being A1

```
Dim SearchCriteria as string
Dim CheckRow, CheckCol, i,j, HitCounter as long

SearchCriteria = "id1"
i = 10
j = 10
HitCounter = 0

For CheckRow = 1 to i
    For CheckCol = 1 to j
        If(instr(cells(CheckRow ,CheckCol ),SearchCritera) <> 0 then 'If the criteria is found in the cell
            HitCounter = HitCounter + 1
            Exit For 'Exit the column loop and go to the next row
        End if

    Next j
Next i

MsgBox "Your criteria was found in " & HitCounter & " different rows"
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it @Siva. Now i feel how ridiculous it was to ask.